# How to obtain File handle to a resource on runtime classpath?

Tags: java, file-io, classpath

I have a situation where I need to scan the runtime classpath for a resource file (say, `res/config/meta.cfg`), and then create a `File` handle for it. The best I've been able to come up with is:

```
// This file is located inside a JAR that is on the runtime classpath.
String fileName = "res/config/meta.cfg";

try {
    InputStream inStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(fileName);
    File file = new File(String.format("${java.io.tmpdir}/%s", fileName));
    FileOutputStream foutStream = null;
    foutStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    while((read = inStream.read(bytes)) != -1)
        foutStream.write(bytes, 0, read);

    foutStream.close();

    return file;
} catch (Exception exc) {
    throw new RuntimeException(exc);
}
```

So essentially, read in the resource as an `InputStream`, and then write the stream to a temp file (under `{$java.io.tmpdir}`) so that we can obtain a valid `File` handle for it.

**This seems like going 3 sides around the barn.** Is there a better/easier/more elegant way of doing this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Of course you can (and probably should) [use a library to copy](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) the `InputStream`'s content to a file but that obviously is not the point of your question.

The classpath does not consist of directories only; resources can be inside archives (typically JARs) or on servers, and may not exist as something that can be accessed via a `java.io.File` object.

Typically the core problem is to use `java.io.File` objects where an `InputStream` would be sufficient. Sometimes you can't do anything against it when using a third-party library but it is a hint that the library designers didn't work very carefully. If you need the file handle in your own code you should have another look why it can't be an `InputStream`. Most of the time it can.

Comment: "you should have another look why it can't be an InputStream." well said :)